# Setting up mysql-connector-python in Docker file

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, protocol-buffers, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to set up a mysql connection that will work with SqlAlchemy in Python 3.6.5 . I have the following in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip3 install -r /event_git/requirements.txt
```

I also have, in requirements.txt:

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.15
```

However, I am not able to connect to the DB. Is there anything else that I need to do to set this up?

Update:
I got 8.0.5 working but not 8.0.15 . Apparently, a protobuff dependency was added; does anyone know how to handle that?

docker file is:

```
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip fontconfig wget nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
# Copy contents of this directory (i.e. full source) to image
COPY . /my_project
# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r /event_git/requirements.txt
# Set event_git folder as working directory
WORKDIR /my_project
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```

I am running it via

```
docker build -t event_git .;docker run -t -i event_git /bin/bash
```

and then executing a script; the db is on my local machine. This is working on mysql-connector-python==8.0.5 but not 8.0.15, so the setup is ok; I think I just need to fulfill the protobuff dependency that was added (see https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/5537 for mention of protobuff dependency).

Comment: can you share your Dockerfile and the command you use to run the container? Also from where are you trying to connect? Localhost or another container? What is the error you get? Please provide more information

Comment: Hi @Mihai , my docker file is:

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip fontconfig wget nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
# Copy contents of this directory (i.e. full source) to image
COPY . /my_project
# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r /event_git/requirements.txt
# Set event_git folder as working directory
WORKDIR /my_project
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

I am running it via `docker build -t event_git .;docker run -t -i event_git /bin/bash` and then executing a script; the db is on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql-connector-python` has the Python Protobuf as an installation requirement, this means that `protobuf` will be installed along `mysql-connector-python`.
If this doesn't work, try to add `protobuf==3.6.1` in your requirements.txt.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the (very) late reply. Unfortunately, I tried that and it did not work. Do you know if there is some command that I need to put in the docker file?

Comment: You can add in docker file: `RUN pip3 install protobuf`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. The key is that `import mysql.connector` needs to be at the top of the file where the create_engine is. Still not sure of the exact reason, but at the very least that seems to define `_CONNECTION_POOLS = {}`. If anyone knows why, please do give your thoughts.